# How to update table while looping the select command?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabase"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
try
{
    conn.Open();
    string cmdUpdate = "UPDATE mem SET name =@name";
    string cmd = "SELECT * FROM mem;";
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(cmd, conn);
    SqlCommand commUpdate = new SqlCommand(cmdUpdate, conn);
    SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["date"].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (date < DateTime.UtcNow)
        {
            commUpdate.Parameters.Clear();
            commUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Done");
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

This is my code.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

This is my connection string.

I want to update the name while retrieve data and match the condition. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Change from : comm.ExecuteNonQuery(); to : commUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call ExecuteReader then to ensure there are results use HasRows. Also rather than adding/clearing parameters on each iteration of the loop, create the parameter once and re-use it as shown below. Lastly, it's good form to select only the fields you require rather than SELECT * FROM.

```
public class Demo
{
    public void Example()
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string cmdUpdate = "UPDATE mem SET name =@name";
            string cmd = "SELECT * FROM mem;";
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(cmd, conn);
            SqlCommand commUpdate = new SqlCommand(cmdUpdate, conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@name", DbType = System.Data.DbType.String });
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["date"].ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    if (date < DateTime.UtcNow)
                    {
                        commUpdate.Parameters["@name"].Value = "Done";
                        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```